# onCreateOptionsMenu() is not getting called on FragmentActivity

Tags: android, menu

Colleagues, `MainActivity` class is derived from `FragmentActivity`, and for some reason activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is not getting called.  I have the first breakpoint in `onCreate()`, which is getting triggered, and the second one in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, which is not getting triggered.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentPagerAdapter m_fragmentPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager m_viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the  primary sections of the activity.
        m_fragmentPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        m_viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        m_viewPager.setAdapter(m_fragmentPagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fragments in this app don't have their own menus.  One menu belonging to the activity "covers" everything.

Theme is Holo.Light

What prevent `onCreateOptionsMenu()` from getting called?  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried extending `AppCompatActivity` instead? That will add a toolbar that displays the menu. Note you might have to change your theme in this case.

Comment: @George  I know that I'm targeting only the newer versions of Android (from 4.3 onward).  As far as I understand, AppCompat enables older versions of the API to do things that have been introduced in newer versions.  I feel, however, that AppCompat is a patch that I should be able to do without.  (Of course, it's possible that my understanding about the history and purpose of AppCompat is off.)  Changing the base class to `AppCompatActivity` did bring the menu, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-check that you have really set the app theme to `Holo.Light`.  I can't explain what is causing the problem, but I was able to reproduce it.  After experimenting with changes between `FragmentActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`, I accidentally ran with `FragmentActivity` and theme set to `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.  This created the behavior you are seeing, with `onCreateOptionsMenu()` not called.

As a side issue, you should fix your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to call through to super as noted in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)): "Deriving classes should always call through to the base implementation".

Comment: Thanks.  Your hunch that I haven't actually set the app theme to `Holo.Light` was correct.

Comment: In the process of blundering though all this, I've come across two samples that demonstrate fragments. [This one from Aug 2012](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html) derives from `Activity` and doesn't use legacy support libraries. [This one from Oct 2013](http://www.codepuppet.com/2013/10/06/using-fragments-in-android-with-fragmentactivity/) uses `FragmentActivity`. Since `Activity` seems to be able to work with fragments, is it always necessary to use `FragmentActivity`? (This app of mine will be written from scratch, and I don't have to support ancient devices.)

Comment: @NickAlexeev: You can use `Activity` instead of `FragmentActivity` if you don't need to support devices older than API 11.  Devices with API less then 11 are now about 3%, according to this [dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
setHasOptionsMenu();//call it from onCreate(); or onViewCreated();
```

This method only used in fragment to tell the activity that this fragment has an option menu.

Answer (score -3):

Add setHasOptionsMenu(true); in your onCreate() method.

Comment: OP is trying to get it to show in the `Activity` not a `Fragment`

Comment: `FragmentActivity` doesn't have `setHasOptionsMenu()` method.

Comment: Did you try to call return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); in your onCreateOptionsMenu();?