# Call onCreateOptionsMenu when page is loaded

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I have a little problem I want show a menu in my action bar when own_product is true but when i change the value of my boolean the menu it still not visible, the boolean var change later.

```
private var own_product = false    

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        println(own_product)
        return if(own_product){
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.product_details_menu,menu)
            true
        } else false
    }
fun myfunction(){
 productViewModel.getProductById(id).observe(this, Observer {

            product = it
            if(product.user_id == auth.currentUser!!.email){
                own_product = true
            }
            println(own_product)
            title.text = product.title
            description.text = product.description
            date.text = product.date.toString()
            image.setImageBitmap(product.image)
            price.text = product.price.toString() +"€"
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try calling `super.onCreateOptionsMenu` before you call `menuInflater` also make sure you have `setHasOptionMenu(true)` in your `onCreate`. Source: [onCreateOptionsMenu not getting called - Bob Snyder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35054179/16653700).

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the menu you should use below code after your boolean changes

1. Fragment

   `requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()`
2. Activity

   `invalidateOptionsMenu()`

This would notify android that contents of menu has changed and it will redraw the menu with new value